# Android camera image preview is not correct

Tags: android

I am trying to write a class that shows the preview of the camera surface in android. I have tried the following code. But the preview is not showing up. I tried changing the parameters but no luck. I have gone through the logcat. Nothing is shown, no error or warning. Only a black screen is shown. The app doesnot crash.

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Camera camera;

public Preview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setFixedSize(50, 50);
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("error", "Can't set camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    if (this.holder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems here that you have not included the type of the holder. You need to set the type to `SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS`. Use below line after adding callback

```
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

So your constructor should be like below

```
public Preview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    holder.setFixedSize(50, 50);
}
```

I have tried the code. It works perfectly now.